# How to use gmplot to scatter plot 3 different colors on Google Map?

Tags: python, plot

I'm having trouble using Python's gmplot library, considering there is not a thorough guidance (in my opinion) of using the library. More specifically, I'm having trouble scatter plotting Google Map with 3 different colors. The following is the sample of my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gmplot import gmplot
import os
import pandas as pd

#This is the filename of the Excel that contains the longitudes and latitudes
file ='CensusTrackCluster.xlsx'

#Input the Excel file using Panda
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)

#Parse the sheet that contains the latitudes and longitudes into a data frame
df = xl.parse('Sheet4')

#Possible colors
colors = ['red','blue','green','purple','orange','yellow','pink','white']

#Subset of the latitudes and longitudes
k1,k2 = df['lats.1'].tolist()[0:4], df['lngs.1'].tolist()[0:4]
j1,j2 = df['lats'].tolist()[0:4], df['lngs'].tolist()[0:4]
m1,m2 = df['lats.2'].tolist()[0:4], df['lngs.2'].tolist()[0:4]

#Plot the scatter plot on the map
gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(34.053132754059298, -118.273844602339, 10)
gmap.scatter(k1,k2, colors[0], size=60, marker=False)
gmap.scatter(j1,j2, colors[1], size=60, marker=False)
gmap.scatter(m1,m2, colors[1], size=60, marker=False)
gmap.draw("test.html")
```

It would at most give me 2 colors on the map when I permutate the order of the function, such as

```
gmap.scatter(k1,k2, colors[0], size=60, marker=False)
gmap.scatter(m1,m2, colors[1], size=60, marker=False)
gmap.scatter(j1,j2, colors[1], size=60, marker=False)
```

Can anyone explain how I can solve this problem? Or is there other ways to scatter plot on Google Map using more than 2 different colors in Python?

Comment: I'm confused since you never use `colors[2]`, instead, you plot both the second and third point with `colors[1]`.

Comment: Is there any correlation between marker size and circle diameter on the map?
For example is size=60 equal to circle of diameter 60?